# Liferay - Scheduling a job at the time set by user from portal

Tags: java, liferay, scheduler

I am using Liferay 6.2 CE GA4. I have been trying to schedule the execution of a method in the controller of my portlet.

I came across many tutorials in which most of the tutorials provide cases where we could provide the time in liferay-portlet.xml, like [this tutorial](http://pmkathiria.blogspot.com.ee/2013/06/how-to-write-simplecron-scheduler-in.html). But I would like to have the time configured by the user in the portal. So is it possible to get the time and implement a simple scheduling job in my constroller.

**EDIT:** I have a controller like following which does the scheduling job.

```
public class MyController {
    @RenderMapping
    public String defaultView() {
        String cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
        Date dt = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(dt); 
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);

        Trigger trigger = null;  
        try {  
            trigger = TriggerFactoryUtil.buildTrigger(TriggerType.CRON, Scheduler.class.getName(), Scheduler.class.getName(), calendar.getTime(), calendar.getTime(), cron);  
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        Portlet portlet = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById("portlet_id");  
        Message message = new Message();  
        message.put("CONTEXT_PATH", portlet.getContextPath());  
        message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, Scheduler.class.getName());  
        message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, portlet.getPortletId());  

        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
        MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, scheduler);
        try {  
            SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule( trigger, StorageType.PERSISTED, "", DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, message, 5);  
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

        return "view";
    }
}
```

The `Scheduler` class above is defined as below.

```
public class Scheduler implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
        myMethodAtScheduledTime();
    }

    public void myMethodAtScheduledTime() {
        System.out.println("Invoked at " + new Date());
    }
}
```

The method `myMethodAtScheduledTime` is invoked every 10 or 20 seconds. How can I restrict the call to just once. i.e. exactly at the time calendar instance time + 2 min (`calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);`)

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler can be created dynamically.

1. The task you want to run must implement [`MessageListener`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/messaging/MessageListener.java) - an interface with just one `receive(Message)` method.
2. A configurable trigger can be registered through [`SchedulerEngineHelperUtil#schedule`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/scheduler/SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.java) method. The trigger takes message listener class and invocation time as parameters (among others).

See [Creating the scheduler dynamically in liferay](http://liferaytutorial.blogspot.cz/2014/07/creating-scheduler-dynamically-in.html) blog post or [this forum post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11799978) to find some examples.

Comment: Could you please check the updated post now. The scheduler is triggered every 10-20 seconds and it does not stop.